# SQL Server 2005 extract a date from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a view I am creating and I want to group by an extracted date from a column that has a date and time. This is where I am....

```
SELECT     
    ClockCode AS MOnum, SUM(Actual_Hrs) AS Runtothours, TStamp
FROM
    dbo.Raw_Booking
WHERE     
   (Actual_Hrs > 0) AND (ClockCode LIKE 'MO%') 
   AND (TStamp > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY 
   ClockCode, TStamp
```

so while I have it grouped by the `TStamp` column there is a record for each one based on the time... I am looking to get a total amount of run time for each order by date.

The `TStamp` column is formatted as:

```
2013-01-02 08:18:47.000
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Please, use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes

Comment: Yeah... I inherited it... would not have chose it

Comment: Can you tell us the `data type` *of* `TStamp` field please?

Comment: Well then change it! Don't let *developer's debt* like this contaminate your solution forever - fix it!

Comment: It is a string data type

Comment: I don't know how to do it and know that I am not affecting the other side... the ERP system

Comment: If I just change it what should I look to be affected? Anything that it is used in? Queries, reports, views, table linking? Have you done this?

Comment: @marc_s - "Developer's debt."  Stealing that, it is an excellent metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your schema, store it as a date to begin with.  Otherwise, change your group by clause to something similar to...

```
GROUP BY CAST(TStamp AS DATE)
```

EDIT:  Forgot you were in SQL 2005.  You can still do something like the following, but keep in mind this should be considered an ugly, short-term, workaround.  All the comments in this thread about redesigning are completely valid and should be pursued...

```
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(TStamp, 0, 11)
```

Comment: Doh!  I forgot that wasn't valid in SQL 2005.   Editing the code now.

Comment: Casting to datetime isn't going to accomplish that.  The second piece of code will use only the date portion if that is what you want.

Comment: It is saying datetime is the type and so I can't use the substring function... ha ha silly newbie am I... Can you help with that?

Comment: In your comments above you mentioned that TStamp is a string type (i.e. varchar, nvarchar)... if that is the case then SUBSTRING should work.  The error message you are getting implies that TStamp is a datetime column.  In that case you would need something like "GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10), TStamp, 102) which converts the date to a string and takes only the date portion.

Comment: CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, TStamp, 101) AS datetime) that did it thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClockCode AS MOnum
     , SUM(Actual_Hrs) AS Runtothours
     , TStampDate
FROM dbo.Raw_Booking
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT CONVERT(datetime, TStamp, 102) AS TStampDateTime
     ) AS CA1
     CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TStampDateTime), 0) AS TStampDate
     ) AS CA2
WHERE Actual_Hrs > 0 
      AND ClockCode LIKE 'MO%'
      AND TStampDateTime > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-01-01 00:00:00', 102))
GROUP BY ClockCode
        ,TStampDate
```

Comment: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Line 5: Incorrect syntax near 'APPLY'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.